# Logo Families/ecosystems

Tags: logo

I'm doing a research for conceptual Logodesigns which should fit into a ecosystem.

I'm not sure if logosystems, ecosystems or logofamilies are the right terms.

I'm thinking about logosets like the Adobe Creative suite or the logofamily of the wikipedia foundation.
Do you know any other Logofamilies like these two examples?

Thank you.

Comment: Microsoft Office is the best example of this I can think of: [2013](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xPbqJ.png), [2010](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Kldc2.png), all the way down to [1995](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lS7ie.png)

Comment: The practice seems to be most common in software companies or websites.

Comment: An ecosystem is about environmental sciences. It's merely metaphor if used in the context of logos. All that said, I'm not sure this question fits StackExchange. There's no one answer to this. It's merely asking for a bunch of different examples.

Comment: If it was more suited towards what's a process or considerations in developing a logo family/ecosystem I think the question would work so much better. Then, examples could be used as support. I agree with @DA01 as it stands right now.

Comment: @Adam thats exactly where my thinking goes. "Considerations in developing such ecosystems" and "finding an appropriate terminology to improve research on this topic". My english is not precise enough to describe this so I think you guys formed a better description of what I mean. I know that such open questions are actually not allowed on stack exchange. But I thought I'll give it a try anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Family is a correct-ish term. There are various substitute terms available to describe branding and the many types of branding, but they all follow a general structure. The following infographic is a simple yet powerfully obvious example of **some** of the different types of ***brand sets*** (for want of a better term):

[image]

Taken from a report about [managing brand architecture strategy when extending from B2B to B2C](http://www.labbrand.com/knowledge/labreport/how-manage-brand-architecture-strategy-when-extending-b2b-b2c)

Answer (score 10):

Depending on what you're looking for, there are a lot of ways to achieve harmony in an ecosystem of products and/or services. As JohnB said in a comment and as you note, Adobe Creative Suite and Microsoft Office are great examples:

[image: Adobe CS3 icons]

[image: MS Office 2010 icons]

An example that came to mind was the case where sports blogging network [SB Nation redesigned their logos](http://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/archives/its_a_sports_nation_we_are_only_living_in_it.php). Below is a sample, but I encourage you to visit the post to see how disconnected they all were before and how unified they look now:

[image: SB Nation logos]

#### Logos are kind of like Icons

Icons are a lot like logos in terms of the design process. With logos, you're trying to reduce a brand, an idea, a product into something that's simple, memorable, and flexible. With icons, it's a similar story. So when a commenter pointed out that the SB Nation logos reminded him of [Foursquare badges](http://mattersofgrey.com/foursquare-badge-list/), he makes a good connection.

Therefore, it might be worthwhile to check out some icons families, like this one designed by [Susan Kare](http://kare.com/portfolio/22_hyperion.html):

[image: Susan Kare icon sample]

[Here](http://turbomilk.com/portfolio/icons/intuit-customer-manager/) are [some](http://www.yellowicon.com/portfolio/icons/ubuntu) other [icon](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) examples [that](http://webdesignledger.com/freebies/all-the-small-icons-youll-ever-need) could inspire you.

[An image on Wikimedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Icon_design_process_%D1%81%D1%81.png) provides a nice infographic on the icon design process ([Here's a link to the author Andaja's page](http://gentleface.com/custom_icon_design_process.html)...not sure which link will stick around longer.). I reference it for this particular part:

[image: Made by Wikipedia user Andaja, licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported license.]

So, logos or icons that share a color palette, or a type of perspective, or a certain degree or method of abstraction will look more unified.

#### Identity is more than logos

Sometimes the logo stays the same, but a unified ecosystem can still be created by other means. [XL Insurance is a great example](http://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/archives/an_xlent_redesign.php):

[image: XL booklets]

Branding firm Wolff Olins did this for [Staples](http://www.wolffolins.com/work/staples) and [USA Today](http://www.wolffolins.com/work/usa-today):

[image: Staples paper]

[image: USA Today variants]

A final great example is when [Nickelodeon rebranded](http://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/archives/new_nick.php). See how they went from logos that were pretty scattershot to a set of brands that were well-integrated:

[image: Nickelodeon channel redesigns]

You can't go wrong going to sites like [Brand New](http://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/) and [Wolff Olins](http://www.wolffolins.com/work/) to see how brands do it!

Comment: Woah. Great Thank you. I forgot about the sports system like NBA Teamlogos and such. Nickelodeon is an awesome example since my task is exactly to improve a totally inconsistent brand.